# how can i convert this jquery to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i convert this jquery code to **vanilla** Javascript

```
 $("h2:contains('" + search + "')").closest(".element").show();
 $("h2:not(:contains('" + search + "'))").closest(".element").hide();
```

i got the second half of the line to be 
`closest(".element").style.display = "block"` 
but i cant find a way for the first half to work in normal Javascript. I am creating a live search function to match the text in the search input to match the `h2`. if they match it will display the content if not the content will display as none.

Comment: jquery is javascript, if you need a vanilla variant of this javascript, simply grab the code for each of the methods you called form the jquery source, otherwise there is a lot of work to produce this functionality.  The whole point of jQuery is it takes far too long to do this in vanilla JS, so we have a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Jquery [contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) gives you a string of text to look for.

So here you need to get all the `h2` tag and search in their text.

As `h2` elements don't have a value, you should use innerHTML and then instead of contains, you should use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method.

```
var allHTwos= document.getElementsByTagName('h2');
for (i=0; i<allHTwos.length; i++) {
    var gh = allHTwos[i];
    var ts = gh.innerHTML;
    if(ts.includes(search)){
// Do your hide/unhide here
}
}
```